# Why boost shared_ptr atomic operation causes a SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, boost, gdb, shared-ptr, segmentation-fault

I have been monitoring the servers running multi-threaded program.
The information is below.

- OS : CentOS release 6.4 x86_64
- boost : BOOST_LIB_VERSION "1_41"
- ACE version 6.2.3
- apr version 2.0
- apr-util version 2.0
- log4cxx version 2.0
- multi-thread main program

Intermittent was found dead in the program information in GDB core file is shown below.

**CASE 1**

```
    Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".

    Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
    #0  0x00007f709cda7c8c in boost::detail::atomic_increment (pw=0x2d) at /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_gcc_x86.hpp:66
    #1  0x00007f709cda7d68 in boost::detail::sp_counted_base::add_ref_copy (this=0x25)
        at /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_gcc_x86.hpp:133
    #2  0x00007f709cda7e77 in boost::detail::shared_count::shared_count (this=0x7f708fffe8d8, r=...)
        at /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/shared_count.hpp:228
    #3  0x00007f709cda848d in boost::shared_ptr<AudioChunk>::shared_ptr (this=0x7f708fffe8d0) at /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:169
    #4  0x00007f709cdb6ae4 in MediaData::GetPacketDescription (this=0x7f705cd1edd0) at MediaData.cpp:955
```

Source code # 0 and # 4 are shown below.

```
    #0  0x00007f709cda7c8c in boost::detail::atomic_increment (pw=0x2d) at /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_gcc_x86.hpp:66
    56 inline void atomic_increment( int * pw )
    57 {
    58      //atomic_exchange_and_add( pw, 1 );
    59      __asm__
    60    (
    61      "lock\n\t" //
    62      "incl %0":
    63      "=m"( *pw ): // output (%0)
    64      "m"( *pw ): // input (%1)
    65      "cc" // clobbers
    66   ); 
    67 }


    #4  0x00007f709cdb6ae4 in MediaData::GetPacketDescription (this=0x7f705cd1edd0) at MediaData.cpp:955
    953 MediaPacketDescriptionRef MediaData::GetPacketDescription()
    954 {
    955     MediaPacketDescriptionRef packetDescriptionRef = m_mediaPacketDescriptionQueue.front();
    956     m_mediaPacketDescriptionQueue.pop();
    957     return packetDescriptionRef;
    958 }
```

"M_mediaPacketDescriptionQueue" is defined as follows:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<MediaPacketDescription> MediaPacketDescriptionRef
std :: queue <MediaPacketDescriptionRef> m_mediaPacketDescriptionQueue;
```

**CASE 2**

```
    Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
    #0  0x0000000000415e60 in boost::detail::atomic_exchange_and_add (pw=0x5d, dv=-1) at /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_gcc_x86.hpp:50
    #1  0x0000000000415f39 in boost::detail::sp_counted_base::release (this=0x55) at /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_gcc_x86.hpp:143
    #2  0x0000000000415fe9 in boost::detail::shared_count::~shared_count (this=0x7fe8042a09f8, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/shared_count.hpp:217
    #3  0x0000000000416408 in boost::shared_ptr<MediaPacketDescription>::~shared_ptr (this=0x7fe8042a09f0, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:169
    #4  0x000000000041bf3c in std::_Destroy<boost::shared_ptr<MediaPacketDescription> > (__pointer=0x7fe8042a09f0) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_construct.h:90
    #5  0x000000000041bed0 in std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<boost::shared_ptr<MediaPacketDescription>*> (__first=0x7fe8042a09f0, __last=0x7fe804244f30)
        at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_construct.h:100
    #6  0x000000000041be27 in std::_Destroy<boost::shared_ptr<MediaPacketDescription>*> (__first=0x7fe8042a07f0, __last=0x7fe804244f30)
        at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_construct.h:123
    #7  0x000000000041bcbb in std::_Destroy<boost::shared_ptr<MediaPacketDescription>*, boost::shared_ptr<MediaPacketDescription> > (__first=0x7fe8042a07f0, __last=0x7fe804244f30)
        at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_construct.h:149
    #8  0x000000000041b9af in std::deque<boost::shared_ptr<MediaPacketDescription>, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<MediaPacketDescription> > >::_M_destroy_data_aux (this=0x7fe804a29a38, __first=..., __last=...)
        at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/deque.tcc:733
    #9  0x000000000041b661 in std::deque<boost::shared_ptr<MediaPacketDescription>, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<MediaPacketDescription> > >::_M_destroy_data (this=0x7fe804a29a38, __first=..., __last=...)
        at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_deque.h:1653
    #10 0x000000000041a3fe in std::deque<boost::shared_ptr<MediaPacketDescription>, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<MediaPacketDescription> > >::~deque (this=0x7fe804a29a38, __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
        at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_deque.h:790
    #11 0x000000000041930c in std::queue<boost::shared_ptr<MediaPacketDescription>, std::deque<boost::shared_ptr<MediaPacketDescription>, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<MediaPacketDescription> > > >::~queue (this=0x7fe804a29a38,
        __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_queue.h:90
    #12 0x0000000000419433 in MediaData::~MediaData (this=0x7fe804a29860, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at ../orkbasecxx/MediaData.h:55
    #13 0x0000000000419863 in boost::checked_delete<MediaData> (x=0x7fe804a29860) at /usr/include/boost/checked_delete.hpp:34
    #14 0x000000000041ca96 in boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_p<MediaData>::dispose (this=0x7fe804263ac0) at /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_impl.hpp:78
    #15 0x0000000000415f5a in boost::detail::sp_counted_base::release (this=0x7fe804263ac0) at /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_gcc_x86.hpp:145
    #16 0x0000000000415fe9 in boost::detail::shared_count::~shared_count (this=0x7fe804391f10, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/shared_count.hpp:217
    #17 0x00000000004164ce in boost::shared_ptr<MediaData>::~shared_ptr (this=0x7fe804391f08, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:169
    #18 0x00007fe857208d8d in ReportData::~ReportData (this=0x7fe804391f00, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at ReportData.h:34
    #19 0x00007fe857208de1 in boost::checked_delete<ReportData> (x=0x7fe804391f00) at /usr/include/boost/checked_delete.hpp:34
    #20 0x00007fe85720a0b6 in boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_p<ReportData>::dispose (this=0x7fe8044cf900) at /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_impl.hpp:78
    #21 0x0000000000415f5a in boost::detail::sp_counted_base::release (this=0x7fe8044cf900) at /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_gcc_x86.hpp:145
    #22 0x0000000000415fe9 in boost::detail::shared_count::~shared_count (this=0x7fe804b25838, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/shared_count.hpp:217
    #23 0x00007fe8572036ae in boost::shared_ptr<ReportData>::~shared_ptr (this=0x7fe804b25830, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:169
    #24 0x00007fe857209038 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<boost::shared_ptr<ReportData> >::destroy (this=0x7fe8261fab1f, __p=0x7fe804b25830)
        at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/new_allocator.h:115
    #25 0x00007fe857208699 in std::_List_base<boost::shared_ptr<ReportData>, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<ReportData> > >::_M_clear (this=0x7fe8261fac20)
        at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/list.tcc:76
    #26 0x00007fe857207b63 in std::_List_base<boost::shared_ptr<ReportData>, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<ReportData> > >::~_List_base (this=0x7fe8261fac20, __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
        at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_list.h:360
    #27 0x00007fe8572074e0 in std::list<boost::shared_ptr<ReportData>, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<ReportData> > >::~list (this=0x7fe8261fac20, __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
        at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_list.h:418
    #28 0x00007fe857207365 in ReportDatas::Refresh (this=0x7fe8040291e8) at ReportData.cpp:479
```

Source code # 0 and # 28 are shown below.

```
    #0  0x0000000000415e60 in boost::detail::atomic_exchange_and_add (pw=0x5d, dv=-1) at /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_gcc_x86.hpp:50
 35 inline int atomic_exchange_and_add( int * pw, int dv )
 36 {
 37     // int r = *pw;
 38     // *pw += dv;
 39     // return r;
 40
 41     int r;
 42
 43     __asm__ __volatile__
 44     (
 45         "lock\n\t"
 46         "xadd %1, %0":
 47         "=m"( *pw ), "=r"( r ): // outputs (%0, %1)
 48         "m"( *pw ), "1"( dv ): // inputs (%2, %3 == %1)
 49         "memory", "cc" // clobbers
 50     );
 51
 52     return r;
 53 }

    #28 0x00007fe857207365 in ReportDatas::Refresh (this=0x7fe8040291e8) at ReportData.cpp:479
471                 for (std::list<ReportDataRef>::iterator it = toEmpty.begin(); it != toEmpty.end() ; it++)
472                 {
473                         ReportDataRef data = *it;
474                         data->Empty();
475                         m_datas.erase(data->GetId());
476                         LOG4CXX_DEBUG(s_log,  data->GetId() + ": Become empty");
477                 }
478                 logMsg.Format("Refreshed %d datas. New data size:%d", (data - m_datas.size()), m_datas.size());
479                 LOG4CXX_DEBUG(s_log,  logMsg);
```

For CASE1 and Queue.front () it is assumed not to be a problem.
I think that it has to perform normally Queue.front () performs the increase of the reference counter shared_ptr.

The problem is I can not understand why intermittent SIGSEGV occurs in the boost lib atomic operations.

========================================================

Sorry. It is difficult to describe the details in the comment to edit the question text.

Thank you for your answer erikzenker.

I was running your code could get the same results as follows GDB.

```
    Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
    0x000000000040092b in boost::detail::atomic_exchange_and_add (pw=0x20b49, dv=-1) at /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_gcc_x86.hpp:50
    /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_gcc_x86.hpp:50:1141:beg:0x40092b
    Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.192.el6.x86_64 libgcc-4.4.7-16.el6.x86_64 libstdc++-4.4.7-16.el6.x86_64
    (gdb) bt
    #0  0x000000000040092b in boost::detail::atomic_exchange_and_add (pw=0x20b49, dv=-1) at /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_gcc_x86.hpp:50
    #1  0x000000000040098b in boost::detail::sp_counted_base::release (this=0x20b41) at /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_gcc_x86.hpp:143
    #2  0x0000000000400a25 in boost::detail::shared_count::~shared_count (this=0x6044c8, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>) at /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/shared_count.hpp:217
    #3  0x0000000000400ad6 in boost::shared_ptr<int>::~shared_ptr (this=0x6044c0, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>) at /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:169
    #4  0x0000000000401e86 in std::_Destroy<boost::shared_ptr<int> > (__pointer=0x6044c0) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_construct.h:90
    #5  0x0000000000401cb4 in std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<boost::shared_ptr<int>*> (__first=0x6044c0, __last=0x6042c0)
        at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_construct.h:100
    #6  0x0000000000401b25 in std::_Destroy<boost::shared_ptr<int>*> (__first=0x6042d0, __last=0x6042c0) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_construct.h:123
    #7  0x000000000040185b in std::_Destroy<boost::shared_ptr<int>*, boost::shared_ptr<int> > (__first=0x6042d0, __last=0x6042c0)
        at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_construct.h:149
    #8  0x0000000000401366 in std::deque<boost::shared_ptr<int>, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<int> > >::_M_destroy_data_aux (this=0x7fffffffe350, __first=..., __last=...)
        at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/deque.tcc:739
    #9  0x0000000000400df9 in std::deque<boost::shared_ptr<int>, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<int> > >::_M_destroy_data (this=0x7fffffffe350, __first=..., __last=...)
        at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_deque.h:1653
    #10 0x0000000000400b50 in std::deque<boost::shared_ptr<int>, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<int> > >::~deque (this=0x7fffffffe350, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>)
        at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_deque.h:790
    #11 0x0000000000400a7c in std::queue<boost::shared_ptr<int>, std::deque<boost::shared_ptr<int>, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<int> > > >::~queue (this=0x7fffffffe350,
        __in_chrg=<value optimized out>) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_queue.h:90
    #12 0x00000000004008be in main () at testc2.cpp:12
```

When I think of this I think it is very similar to CASE 2.

But I do not yet understand.

I'm thinking that the reference counter of the # 0 of operation increased CASE 1 shared_ptr.

Since success in a non-empty queue element approach think that trying to "# 0 atomic_increment".

Comment: Don't you need to test in case 1 if the std::queue is empty ?

Comment: Yes, I have not "queue empty" checked.
However, if the queue is empty Cause
GDB log is not it should be recorded stl queue content?

Comment: Did you find a solution? It is happening to me right now and I'm clueless

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem here is the removal of an element of a `std::queue` that is empty. You can reproduce the error with the following simple example:

```
// Simplified example
#include <queue>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

int main(){

    std::queue<boost::shared_ptr<int> > queue;
    boost::shared_ptr<int> ptr = queue.front();

    // Remove element from empty queue
    queue.pop();
    return 0;
}
```

Calling the `pop` method on an empty queue is undefined.
You must check if the queue is empty before:

```
    // Solving the problem
    if (!queue.empty()) {
      boost::shared_ptr<int> ptr = queue.front();
      queue.pop();
    }
```

## Edit

As I mentioned above: removing elements from an empty queue is not defined. What happens if you still want to pop or erase an element depends on your stl implementation. Having a look at the implementation used by gcc 6.1 (pop() calls pop_front() of std::deque):

```
  void
  pop_front() _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
  {
  if (this->_M_impl._M_start._M_cur != this->_M_impl._M_start._M_last - 1)
  {
    _Alloc_traits::destroy(this->_M_impl,
                           this->_M_impl._M_start._M_cur);
    ++this->_M_impl._M_start._M_cur;
  }
  else
  _M_pop_front_aux();
  }

 ...

 template <typename _Tp, typename _Alloc>
 void deque<_Tp, _Alloc>::
 _M_pop_front_aux()
 {
   this->_M_impl.destroy(this->_M_impl._M_start._M_cur);
   _M_deallocate_node(this->_M_impl._M_start._M_first);
   this->_M_impl._M_start._M_set_node(this->_M_impl._M_start._M_node + 1);
   this->_M_impl._M_start._M_cur = this->_M_impl._M_start._M_first;
 }
```

By not going to much into detail, you see that the implementation tries to destroy (destruct) the first element of your queue. Destructing a shared pointer means to modify the reference counter. But there is no object that could be modified so it will try to modify memory that it does not own (Segmentation fault).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Can you look at a modified question?

Comment: I edited my answer ...the core is that the queue tries to destruct a shared pointer that does not exist.